# Does shorthand javascript syntax work on older browsers?

Tags: javascript

Toady i was playing a little with shorthand syntax.. and found 2 new cool ways do write the long boring `if` syntax, also learned new things about closures...

this is with what i came up.

it's a toggle function for a accordion menu with one eventHandler.

```
function h(e){
 var p='parentNode',a=e.target,b=a[p],f=48,u='px',y=b[p];
 !y.c||(y.c==b||(y.c.style.height=f+u,y.c.x=f)),
 y.c=y.c==b?null:b,
 a!=b.firstChild||(b.x=b.x>f?f:
 (f+b.childNodes[1].offsetHeight),b.style.height=b.x+u)
}
```

and here is the example.

http://jsfiddle.net/YjCbM/ (tested with Chrome 29)

there was an error .. this is working http://jsfiddle.net/YjCbM/1/

In this example i use e.target, webkit css3 and various other things that ie and other browsers don't support, but appart from that... does this shorthand syntax work on older/other browsers?

ps.:don't tiddy up the code in jsfiddle or nothing works

---

**EDIT**
after i got some answers..

Some useful shorthands

```
var W=window,D=W.document,G='getElementById',
E=W.addEventListener?'addEventListener':'attachEvent',
// this awesome as i don't use jQuery. 
// this way i have a short getElementbyId() like jQuery's $()
// and also a ie compatible addEventListener.

a=D[G](x);
//document.getElementById(x)
a[E]('click',handler);
//a.addEventListener() or a.attachEvent()

a=x?y:x
//if x is defined, true, or not 0 it will take the y value 
if ( x == true ) {
 a = y;
}else{
 a = x;
}

a=x||y;
//if x is not defined it will take y
if ( x == true ) {
 a = x
}else{
 a = y
}


x||(x=y,alert(x)) // <- this is fabulous
// if x is  not defined, not true, or 0 it will set the x with the y value 
// and alert x
if ( x == 'undefined' ) {
 x = y;
 alert ( x );
}
// how manytimes did it happen that you wanted to do just a short check but you hat to 
//set 2-3 variables and could not use a simple  a=x||y
// whith this shorthand you can.

var a = 1;
var b;
var c = a;
// is the same as
var a=1,b,c=a;
```

**edit2**

1. I really didn't know about this type of closures and shorthands
2. The point is not to write javascript this way all the time but to keep a nice code
   and then manually rewrite it this way to have a **FASTER** and **SHORTER** code
3. As you can read in the comments **"Hey, look what I can do!"** ... again... i didn't know about this before i posted this functions and i tested only in chrome at the time.And yeas i write javascript since years ... but not with this shorthand & bitwise operators.this is something new for me.
4. After testing some compression utilities yuy obfuscator and more i found that they can't compress you code like this way so in any case **YOU HAVE TO WRITE A GOOD CODE** and don't hope the various compressors do that for you so **are you trying to manually minify your code?** ... **YES THATS WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO.**

i got a *question ban* for all these downvotes. but i really can't see why i got so many downvotes ... **pls explain your downvotes**.

Comment: The comma operator should be supported by all browsers too.

Comment: Cool, you don't need an obsufcator  with a code like this.

Comment: ... are you trying to manually minify your code? Eesh, you should use better variable names.

Comment: why would you write your code like this?  you know this is usually produced by a tool designed to reduce file size, right?  we don't code golf just for kicks (well, most of the time)

Comment: None of that's new to the ECMA standard. However, as what appears to be a DOM event handler, it won't work in IE<=8 if you're not using something like jQuery or normalizing for IE's attachEvent vs. addEventListener by hand.

Comment: I don't understand how this is even a question. Looks more like, "Hey, look what I can do!" Congratulations, you can write illegible, unmaintainable code.

Comment: `W.D[G](x)` will throw an error, unless you defined `D` in global scope. However, it's shorter to write `D[G](x)`.

Comment: @vol7ron: No, the variables are initialized from left to right and `p` is before `b`. It doesn't have to be in a different statement.

Comment: right felix .. corrected..

Comment: Also, don't call me "Toady."

Comment: @FelixKling retracted my comment - just tested, you're right.  I could have sworn two weeks ago I was working on an object creation pattern where that mattered, but maybe I reversed the order.  Two weeks ago was along time ago - who knows :)

Comment: the point of this question is to manually compress the code after it's finished... i didn't know you could use || and later comma separated variables or functions...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are referring to the ternary operator, `?:`, then yes, that is supported in all browsers.

It's used like this:

```
condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse
```

For example:

```
'You have ' + (milkAmount <= 0 ? 'no' : (milkAmount + ' cups')) + ' of milk!'
```

And if you are referring to the or operator, `||`, then yes to that also. For example:

```
a || b || c
```

This will find the first variable out of `a`, `b`, and `c` and select the first one that is not *falsy* (`undefined`, `0`, `false`, `NaN`, etc).

Comment: and hello||(x=0,alert(r))

Comment: @cocco: A logical OR operator belongs to the very basics of a language I would say. You can expect those things to be supported in browsers.

Comment: a||b||c = a||(b||c) ?

Comment: @cocco No, it just chooses the first one that is truthy. Your second one will do the same, but parenthesis are irrelevant. `a || b || c` === `a || (b || c)` === `(a || b) || c`.

Comment: example for a||b||c||d ?

Comment: cool, i guess you all will start to hate me when i answer the next answers.

Comment: So basically only after the first var a=x i need a ';' then for the rest of the function i can use ','

Comment: @cocco Umm... what? For your `a || b || c || d` read my comments - I already explained that

Comment: @cocco Yes, you can use `,` for the `var`s, but please stop asking more questions in the comments, and please use Google.

Comment: also bitwise operators ? last one.

Comment: @cocco Use Google, please, and don't ask follow-up questions in the comments. A quick five-second Google search will give you the answer to that.

Comment: @cocco: You can expect all the core/basic operators to be supported in all browsers. ES5 didn't introduce any new operators/syntax, only new methods of built in objects. ES6 will probably add new syntax constructs, but that's not of your concern. If you want absolute certainty, have a look at the ECMAScript 1 language specification from 1997: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262-arch.htm.